# Dynamically convert to a type and perform an operation comparing the converted values

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a list of values which are parsed in other place and are populated in the `List<string>compareValues` list.

There is also a `value` with which I need to compare a list of `compareValues` which can be `decimal` (2.50), `int` (10), `Date` (31/07/2018 or 7-31-2018 etc) or a string.

For the comparison operators, I have an enum which looks like:

```
public enum CompareOperation
{
    [Description("=")]
    Equal,
    [Description("<>")]
    NotEqual,
    [Description(">")]
    Greater,
    [Description(">=")]
    GreaterOrEqual,
    [Description("<")]
    Less,
    [Description("<=")]
    LessOrEqual
}
```

The value of the comparison operation is also parsed in other place.

I need to write a method which will perform the operation of the corresponding comparison and return `true` or `false`.

In my method a lot of copy-paste and the question is, how it's better to implement this task more "correctly" to avoid copy-paste?

```
private bool CompareCondition(List<string> compareValues, string value, CompareOperation operation)
{
    int intVal;
    decimal decimalVal;
    DateTime datetimeVal;

    switch (operation)
    {
        case CompareOperation.Equal:
        {

            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intVal))
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => intVal == Int32.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalVal))
            {                        
                return compareValues.Any(x => decimalVal == Decimal.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeVal))
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => datetimeVal == DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
            }
            else
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => x == value);
            }
        }
        case CompareOperation.NotEqual:
        {   
            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intVal))
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => intVal != Int32.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalVal))
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => decimalVal != Decimal.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeVal))
            {
                return compareValues.Any(x => datetimeVal != DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        case CompareOperation.Greater:
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => intVal > Int32.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => decimalVal > Decimal.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => datetimeVal > DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        case CompareOperation.GreaterOrEqual:
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => intVal >= Int32.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => decimalVal >= Decimal.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => datetimeVal >= DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        case CompareOperation.Less:
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => intVal < Int32.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => decimalVal < Decimal.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => datetimeVal < DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        case CompareOperation.LessOrEqual:
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(value, out intVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => intVal <= Int32.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (Decimal.TryParse(value, out decimalVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => decimalVal <= Decimal.Parse(x));
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out datetimeVal))
            {
                return compareValue.Any(x => datetimeVal <= DateTime.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason that the `compareValues` are assumed to be parsable in the type that `value` can be parsed to?

Comment: I looks like you haven't posted your actual code because it contains invalid variable names and does not compile. Everyting below `NotEqual` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve flatten the outter `switch`-block and the inner `if-else` block, since the nested block is almost identical in all the cases, except the fallback string comparison when the operation is “equal”. 
And, I’ve also moved the `compareValues` parameter to the last position, so we can take advantage of `params` array. It is also make it more clear when you use less or greater types of comparison:

```
CompareCondition("1", ConpareOperation.Less, “1”, “0")
```

```
private bool CompareCondition(string value, CompareOperation operation, params string[] compareValues) => CompareCondition(value, operation, compareValues.AsEnumerable());
private bool CompareCondition(string value, CompareOperation operation, IEnumerable<string> compareValues)
{
    var parsers = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>
    {
        [typeof(int)] = x => int.TryParse(x, out var intResult) ? intResult : default(object),
        [typeof(decimal)] = x => decimal.TryParse(x, out var decimalResult) ? decimalResult : default(object),
        [typeof(DateTime)] = x => DateTime.TryParse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateTimeResult) ? dateTimeResult : default(object),
    };
    var compareOperators = new Dictionary<CompareOperation, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression>>
    {
        [CompareOperation.Equal] = Expression.Equal,
        [CompareOperation.NotEqual] = Expression.NotEqual,
        [CompareOperation.Greater] =  Expression.GreaterThan,
        [CompareOperation.GreaterOrEqual] = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual,
        [CompareOperation.Less] = Expression.LessThan,
        [CompareOperation.LessOrEqual] = Expression.LessThanOrEqual,
    };

    // determine the type to compare
    var comparable = parsers
        .Select(x => new { Type = x.Key, Value = x.Value(value), Parser = x.Value })
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value != null);
    if (comparable == null)
    {
        // perform a string comparison when operation is equal as fallback
        return operation == CompareOperation.Equal
            ? compareValues.Any(x => x == value)
            : false;
    }

    // building expression: (a,b) => a __OPERATOR__ b;
    var a = Expression.Parameter(comparable.Type, "a");
    var b = Expression.Parameter(comparable.Type, "b");
    var compareOperator = compareOperators[operation](a, b);
    var compare = Expression.Lambda(compareOperator, a, b).Compile();

    return compareValues
        .Any(x => comparable.Parser(x) is object result && (bool)compare.DynamicInvoke(comparable.Value, result));
}
```

Note: The `a is object x` pattern evaluates to false when `a` is null.

Comment: Since you are not caching the compiled expression and use the `DynamicInvoke ` this solution would be terribly slow.